# Probability of the sum of two numbers

Tags: probability

A random generator of a computer generates two real numbers $x_1,x_2\in[0,1]$.

Which is the probability that $0.4\le x_1+x_2\le1.6$ ?

Comment: Can you describe your efforts and where they have failed?

Comment: Which are the needed events?

Comment: We assume independence,  and that the two distributions can be viewed as continuous uniform. Draw the square with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(0,1)$. Label the axes $x_1$ and $x_2$. Draw the lines $x_1+x_2=0.4$ and $x_1+x_2=1$. We want the probability of landing between these two lines.

Comment: This is a good solution but I want to prove it by a probability computation, i.e. $P[0.4<=x_1+x_2<=0.6]=...$

Comment: Use geometry to compute the probability! The area of the square beneath $x_1+x_2= 1.6$ is $P(x_1+x_2\le 1.6)$ and the area of the square beneath $x_1+x_2= 0.4$ is $P(x_1+x_2\le 0.4)$ so that $$P(0.4\le x_1+x_2\le 1.6)=P(x_1+x_2\le 1.6)-P(x_1+x_2\le 0.4).$$

Comment: My answer is a 'probability simulation'. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No. thx! I wanted one such the geometric solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability you are after is equal to the area of
$$A:=\bigl\{(x_1,x_2)\in[0,1]^2\>\bigm|\> 0.4\leq x_1+x_2\leq 1.6\bigr\}\ ,$$
which is easily seen to be $=1-0.4^2=0.84$.

Comment: This is an elegant, rigorous version of my second 'intuitive approach'.

Comment: Someone else might make a better one, but [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfBuh.png) is a picture that helps visually.(Feel free to use it if you want.) Oh, I just noticed that Bruce Trumbo has added a nice one in his answer, as well.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use the joint density. Here is another approach that employs the tower law.
\begin{align*}
P(0.4 \leq x_1+x_2 \leq 1.6) &= E( P(0.4 \leq x_1+x_2 \leq 1.6 \mid x_2))\\
&= E(\min(1.6-x_2, \, 1) - \max(0.4-x_2, \, 0))\\
&=\int_0^{0.4} (0.6+x)\,dx + \int_{0.4}^{0.6} dx + \int_{0.6}^1 (1.6 -x)\, dx\\
&=0.84.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

First, the simulation (in R):

```
 m = 10^6;  x1 = runif(m);  x2 = runif(m)
 y = x1 + x2;  mean(y > .4 & y < 1.6)
 ## 0.840271  # approx. by simulation
 1 - .4^2
 ## 0.84      # exact by geometry (not calculus)
```

Second, an intuitive approach: The PDF of $Y$ consists of two similar triangular regions.
(By calculus or by analogy with the well-known discrete distribution
of the sum of numbers two dice.)
Support is $(0, 2).$ Each of the two small triangles
excluded [above $(0,.4)$ and $(1.6,2)$, respectively]
has base .4 and height .4. Thus the exact probability
is 0.84. The plot at left below shows a histogram of the simulated
values of $Y$ along with its density function.

[image]

Another intuitive approach:  To begin, you have a uniform
distribution above the unit square [vertices at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.
Which two triangles within the square must be excluded to get the
the desired event? (Plot at right above. See comment by @AndreNicholas.)